# How to use a connection pool to an aerospike server

Tags: go, aerospike

I want to connect to an aerospike server using golang

I am not able to get any library that gives such an option 
Default golang libraries for redis etc have clear pooling examples. Not sure why they are missing for aerospike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to. The Go client for aerospike automatically pools the connections internally.

You just need to make a `Client` to the database and hang on to that single instance, and that object will take care of the rest for you. There are a few variables you can set in the `ClientPolicy` to tweak the internal connection pool.